# Work Problem: Painting a Home

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A and B working together can finish painting a home in six days. A working alone can finish it in 5 days less than B. How long will it take each of them to finish the work alone?

The answer is $B = 15$, $A = 10$. I tried:

$${ { \frac{1}{A} }+{ \frac{1}{B} }={ \frac{1}{6} } }$$
$${ { \frac{1}{A} }={ \frac{1}{B}-{ \frac{1}{5} } } }$$

I get $B = 5.454545$. What am I doing wrong? Any hints?

Comment: The first rate equation should be correct.  But I think you may want to express the second sentence as $ \ A \ = \ B \ - \ 5 \ $ : this isn't about rates, but a statement about times to completion.  (You will get two solutions for B, but in conjunction with the result for A, one of those is spurious.)

Comment: Perhaps a source of error is that you never wrote down explicitly what $A$ and $B$ stand for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second equation should be

$$
A = B-5
$$

since in the first equation, you are using $A$ and $B$ to represent the number of days each person would require to complete the job alone.

Alternatively, you could rewrite the equations as

$$
A+B = \frac{1}{6}
$$
$$
\frac{1}{A} = \frac{1}{B}-5
$$

where $A$ and $B$ now represent the fraction of the job each person completes in a single day.

Comment: The algebra for your second approach is a bit "hairier", but it is otherwise another good way to view the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ and $B$ are meant to represent the time required by each painter to finish the house solo, then I agree with your first equation.  Thinking of time in this way I also agree with @Brian that the second equation should be as he has stated it: how much less time the first painter requires relative to the second painter.  Equivalently, $B=A+5$.

For me, a convenient way to think of the problem is in terms of rates which leads to a different meaning of $A$ and $B$. Let $T$ be the amount of time it takes for the first painter to complete one house.  Then define the rate of work for the first painter to be
$$ A = \frac{1 \ house}{T \ days} ,$$
the rate of work for the second painter to be
$$ B = \frac{1 \ house}{(T+5) \ days},$$
and the combined rate of work of both painters to be 
$$ A + B = \frac{1 \ house}{6 \ days}.$$

Then by substitution in the third equation we have that
$$\frac{1}{T} + \frac{1}{(T+5)} = \frac{1}{6}.$$

Solve for feasible values of $T$ to get the time required for the first painter to do the job solo.  Add $5$ to get the time for the second painter.